# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator error for prepared statement

Tags: sql, jdbc, syntax-error, prepared-statement

```
final String selectCustomerAttributes =
                    "SELECT * FROM CM9_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES WHERE (ENTITY_TYPE,ENTITY_ID) IN ( ? ) ";          
        
 ps = con.prepareStatement(selectCustomerAttributes);           
 ps.setString(1, inputAttributes);          
 result = ps.executeQuery();
```

I was trying to bind the String(inputAttributes variable here) "**('BA','2312') , ('Sub','523')**" to the above prepared statement(ps variable here) and getting stuck with invalid relational operator syntax error. Please suggest how to overcome the error

Comment: JDBC doesn't support this syntax.  You will have to use a workaround, or dynamically generate the query.

Comment: getting same err with SELECT * FROM CM9_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES WHERE (ENTITY_TYPE,ENTITY_ID) IN ( ? ,?) and binding with  ('BA','2312')  and  ('Sub','523')